# "Illegal Byte sequence" error while using shell commands in mac bash terminal

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, uniq

Getting "illegal byte sequence" error while trying to extract non English characters from a large file in MacOS bash shell.
This is the script that I am trying to use:

```
sed 's/[][a-z,0-9,A-Z,!@#\$%^&*(){}":/_-|. -][\;''=?]*//g' < $1 >Abhineet_extract1.txt;
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\
/g' <Abhineet_extract1.txt | sort | uniq |tr -d '\n' >&1;
rm Abhineet_extract1.txt;
```

and here is the error that I am getting:

```
uniq: stdin: Illegal byte sequence
```

'+?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that a UTF-8 locale is causing `Illegal byte sequence`.

Instead say:

```
LC_CTYPE=C your_command
```

`man locale` says:

```
   These environment variables affect each locale categories for all
   locale-aware programs:

   LC_CTYPE

           Character classification and case conversion.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The error is gone but the output now contains only '+? characters. I was feeding the output from a sqlite query to the script. I formatted the output to csv and then my script started working.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're saying.  Please update your question instead.

Comment: I ran into this issue while deleting some sensitive data from my git history using `git filter-branch --tree-filter "find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/originalpassword/newpassword/g' {} \;"` and it worked like a charm

Comment: So, is this an issue with Sort? does FreeBSD still suffer from this problem? or should I just file a bug with Apple and tell them to update their ancient ass bin/utils?